# Why did React stop running after saving changes to the code?

Tags: reactjs

**During the process of creating a React application, automatic page refresh worked, but today after another day of working on the code, I noticed that when saving any changes in the code, the browser stopped responding to them, and you need to click on refresh the page in order for the changes to become visible.
There are no errors in the console.**

*What could be the problem?*

Git repo: [link](https://github.com/YevheniiBrodovskyii/Hotel-Review-App)

Answer (score 3):

There is an issue with some versions of react-script packages that insert an unnecessary document body in the DOM. If this is the problem you can solve it here [Github Issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11880).